# Unable to catch std::invalid_argument in `catch(const std::exception &ex)`

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
void App::start()
try
{
    initialize();
    //...

    m_errorCode = 0;
}
catch (const std::exception &ex)
{
    std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
    m_errorCode = -1;
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "Unknown exception\n";
    m_errorCode = -2;
}

void App::initialize()
{
    m_controller = createController();
    //...
}

std::unique_ptr<IController> App::createController() const
{
    if (m_config.m_controllerType == "iot_v1")
    {
        return std::make_unique<ControllerIotV1>();
    }

    if (m_config.m_controllerType == "iot_v2")
    {
        return std::make_unique<ControllerIotV2>();
    }

    throw new std::invalid_argument("Unsupported controller type.");
}
```

I am unable to catch `std::invalid_argument` in the `catch (const std::exception &ex)` block. The `catch(...)` block is being triggered instead. But as far as I know, `std::invalid_argument` inherits from `std::exception` and should be catchable by the first block. Is it? I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: The main thing you're missing is a minimal, complete example that compiles, runs, and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Read up on what `new` does.

Comment: `const std::exception &ex` ≠ `std::exception const* ex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your should throw by value (without `new`):

```
throw std::invalid_argument("Unsupported controller type.");
```